# HP Wireless Printer not working

Tags: windows-7, printing

I have installed an HP DeskJet 4620 driver on a win 7 machine.
All works perfectly for several days, and than printing is not longer possible. Instead I get the message: "Unable to communicate with printer".

This happened on every Win 7 PC I tried, and none of the HP/MS sites contain any relevant info...

Comment: Please remove the solution from your question, and post it as an answer instead. You can then chose to accept this as your answer after 48 hours.

Comment: I know. I couldn;t do that when I wrote the question due to a stack exchange limitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that HP installation puts a unique "port" called "HP Network re-discovery". It stops working after some time (possibly after the first time the printer/pc enter sleep mode).

BUT, the standard MS TCP port works just fine.

So:

1. Go to "Printers"
2. Right click Printer
3. Click "Printer properties" and then "Printer" or "Fax" (for both - do all this twice)
4. Click "Add Port..."
5. Select "Standard TCP Port"
6. Fill in details
7. Move printer to use the new port by un-checking the old one and checking the new one

Happy printing

Comment: Thanks Omri !!
Your solution helped me print my documents just on time before a meeting.
The HP windows application could see the printer, but windows could not (and thus i couldn't print).
I choose Standard TCP Port as you suggested (iso the HP), restarted the computer, and it worked!
Toda!